# PrintManager Android shows black screen

Tags: android, printing, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to create a project that contains a button with a function attached to call a PrintManager. I have try Google's [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) but when I click the button it shows a black screen and nothing happens, no crashing or anything. My code is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintJob;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Print_Button);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doWebViewPrint();
            }
        });

    }

    private void doWebViewPrint() {
        // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("MYAPP-------------", "page finished loading " + url);
               // createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });


        webView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/about/index.html");

        // Keep a reference to WebView object until you pass the PrintDocumentAdapter
        // to the PrintManager
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        // Get a print adapter instance
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("MyDocument");

        // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }

}
```

I have set the API to 21, and I am running it on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0, so in theory, it should works.

I have also checked that the "Log.i("MYAPP-------------", "page finished loading " + url);" appears in the console so the button is working.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No, I didn't. I needed this in order to use in Unity, and I finally found a compiled library that do this, but I have no the source code, sorry. But I still would like to know, the reason it doesn't work for personal pride =P